# Is there a normalized way to send request execution duration in HTTP Headers?

Tags: http, httpresponse, network-protocols

I believe everything is in the question !

Proposals : 
- "Execution Duration"
- "Exec Time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *standard* HTTP request header for a client to request the maximum time that a request can run for, or a *standard* HTTP response header for a server to specify how long a request took to run.  In the latter case, the best you could do with *standard* headers is subtract the date/time of the request `Date` header from the date/time of the response `Date` header.

If you are implementing your own HTTP server, you can certainly create your own custom `X-...` header(s) for handling durations, but that would not be *standard* behavior, and only custom clients that support your header(s) would be able to utilize them.